# How to makeprg gcc pipe tee errors.err in vim?

Tags: gcc, vim, makefile, tee

I want to pipe `stderr` from `gcc` to `tee errors.err` but I got no luck trying this two pieces I made up:

```
setlocal makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -Wextra\ -g\ -O0\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ %\ -o\ %<.x\ 2>\ >(tee\ errors.err)
```

The file is there, but its blank. At first I thought `:make` was deleting it, but even using `set makeef=makeerrors.err` the `errors.err` file was still blank.

The other (and actually my previous) solution was:

```
setlocal makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -Wextra\ -g\ -O0\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ %\ -o\ %<.x\ 2>&1\ |\ tee\ errors.err
```

But I got this error I never figured out how to eliminate: `E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &`

---

Edit 1: I've tried to use other filename also, like `teerrors.err`, just in case. Same problem.

Edit 2: I also tried:

```
set shellredir=2>errorsredir.err
!gcc % -o %<.x
```

to no avail. But, anyway, this wouldn't be a solution, because I cant set `makeprg` to a filter.

Edit 3: This one (extra `\` in the pipe)

```
setlocal makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -Wextra\ -g\ -O0\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ %\ -o\ %<.x\ 2>&1\ \|\ tee\ teeerrors.err
```

Gives vim error: `E492: Not an editor command:  tee teeerrors.err`

I just run out of ideas.

Comment: You can safely forget about `makeprg`.  It's broken by design, and it will never do whayt you want.  You might stand more chances if you use `system()` and `cgetexpr` instead, provided that you read the sources and figure out the right incantations for `shell`, `shellcmdflag`, `shellpipe`, `shellquote`, `shellredir`, `shellslash`, `shelltemp`, `shellxquote`, and `shellxescape`.  Yes, it's that bad.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment, although not solved the question, was a nice inspiration. I started to play with `makeprg=bash -c...`, just to realize, due to error messages, that `makeprg` was itself using `bash -c...`. So I simplified things (see answer bellow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Simpler than I thought.

```
:set makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -Wextra\ -g\ -O0\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ %\ -o\ %<.x\ 2>errors.err;\ cat\ errors.err
```

Bottom line: you can't pipe. (At least I couldn't find a solution with pipes).

Comment: added to my `c.vim` plugin. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but... You can use pipe, just add additional double backslash:

```
setlocal makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -Wextra\ -g\ -O0\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ %\ -o\ %<.x\ 2>&1\ \\\|\ tee\ teeerrors.err
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a closer look.